# PHP-Laravel Implement user authentication via username and password

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

So I am developing a web-app with Laravel as back-end and VueJs as front end, in which I would like to implement `Okta` as SSO. I would like to implement authentication in following manner.

1. User comes on the website and provide username and password via login form.
2. Send post request to the server with user inputs.
3. Verify user credentials on Okta and generate token
4. Send token as response of login api.

I have searched the Okta documents about how to implement this. And I found `Identity engine` implementation via `Identity engine sdk`. But I have not found any such Identity engine sdk for PHP or Laravel. So my question is

1. Is this even possible in PHP?
2. If yes, Can you provide any documentation or working demo to check?
3. If not, What are the other option to achieve this?
   Thank you in advance.

Comment: Okta itself has documentation about a laravel integration https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/11/04/protecting-a-laravel-api-with-jwt and https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/09/05/laravel-authentication

Comment: I am sorry @JohnZwarthoed if I am not clear in my question. I have studied this document, but they do not provide what I am looking for. I am looking for a way to authenticate user via username and password without redirecting them to `Okta portal`

Comment: Why go through all the trouble of using a SSO provider like Okta when you're not gonna use its core function. Might be better of with a simple laravel authentication.

Comment: In my web-app I am going to utilise content from other platforms too via deep linking. So for that I need SSO.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using Laravel Socialite with a open-source provider for Okta. https://socialiteproviders.com/Okta/#okta

Comment: Yes @morten we can use `socialite` but the tutorial [https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/09/05/laravel-authentication] I found is redirecting user to `Okta` for verification which I do not want in my implementation flow.

Answer (score 0):

Good question.
Will this help you? - https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-php

Comment: Thank you @kevin for the suggestion, but unfortunately this sdk do not provide ability to verify application user via `username and password` which is my primary requirement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).